# Getting an syntax error by using RasPiArduino for Raspberry Pi

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi

I am using an Raspberry Pi Zero with an L298n motor driver to control two motors. I was testing the motors using a Python script. That worked fine.

Now I wanted to use the Arduino software to program the motors. I was following this tutorial on how to archive that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZvhtfUlY8Y

Then I coded this into the Arduino software (v. 1.8.5)

```cpp
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Console.println("Setup Einstellungen");
  pinMode(17, OUTPUT);
  delay(500);
  Console.println("Setup Einstellungen Ende");
}

void loop() {
  Console.println("Rechts Vorwärts");
  digitalWrite(17, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(17, LOW);
  delay(5000);
}
```

I compiled the file using "Export compiled Binary". I uploaded it on the Raspberry using FileZilla and tried to run it via SSH.

When I tried to run it with:

```
(sudo) sketch_feb28.ino.bplus.bin
```

I got the following error:

> : -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `sketch_feb28.ino.bplus.bin'

Running `file sketch_feb28.ino.bplus.bin`

```
sketch_feb28a.ino.bplus.bin: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SY            SV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2            .0, BuildID[sha1]=a0260345a3700dca64c63fde8a10959214ce9b85, not stripped
```

I cannot solve this issue alone.

Comment: Can you please add the result of `file sketch_feb28.ino.bplus.bin`? The error message looks like you don't have a valid binary here

Comment: Do you want me to upload the file somewhere?

Comment: No, just run the command and [add the output to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49210136/edit). The `file` command tells you what type of file you have

Comment: Since you mentioned Putty, you need to run the command on your Raspberry Pi, not on the Windows PC

Comment: I have added the output of the command to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure, where the syntax error comes from.

Run the file with:

```
./sketch_feb28.ino.bplus.bin
```

This is the syntax for running a binary, that is not in PATH. Since the file is a valid executable, the error message should vanish.

Comment: Thank you very much. Running the file with: `sudo ./sketch_feb28a.ino.bplus.bin` has solved the issue.